# Should GAC Publisher Policies themselves be versioned

Tags: .net, wix, gac

After god-only-knows how much pain and suffering I have succesfully installed both my assembly and a publisher policy into the GAC using WIX. However, I noticed that when I installed subsequent versions of MSI, the policy was not being updated.

I figured this was because WIX wasn't seeing a change in the policy assembly, so at build-time I now set both the FileVersion and ProductVersion of the policy assembly (using the AL.EXE command line switches).

This seems to work fine. However looking in the GAC I now have multiple side-by-side versions of my publisher policy as well as the multiple versions of my assembly:

- MyAssembly
- - v4.0_1.0.0.10_strongname
- - v4.0_1.0.0.11_strongname
- - v4.0_1.0.0.12_strongname
- Policy.1.0.MyAssembly
- - v4.0_1.0.0.10_strongname
- - v4.0_1.0.0.11_strongname
- - v4.0_1.0.0.12_strongname

etc...

Everything *seems* to work, and binding is redirected to the later version of the assembly installed. however does anyone know if this will cause problems? I understand the specifications for the file name for the policy assembly, but nowhere really talks about what the version number for the policy assembly should be. Clearly, if they vary, the GAC will allow side-by-side versions (as above). Should I be varying the FileVersion alone?